# BackgroundColor of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle labels?

Tags: uitableview, background

I am trying to create a table with an image as a background.
To achieve this, I started out with the background:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

This resulted in a background image which appears in tablecells as well. That is not something I want, so I tried to set the cell's backgroundColor:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This had no effect at all !!!. Hmmm strange.
So I tried this:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
[backgroundView release];
```

This works almost. The only problem left is that the textLabel & the detailTextLabel still show the background behind them.
Setting the backgroundColor on those labels to white doesn't do anything either.

How do I proceed? Where do I go wrong? I am trying to achieve a tableView like the worldClock app has.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the background colour of the table view cell, you'll need to set it in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` rather than `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
otherwise it won't have any effect, for example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: I still don't full understand why using cellForRowAtIndexPath: doesn't work, but you've solved my problem. Thanks!