# UITableViewCell background color problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I subclassed UITableViewCell to set a cell background color to a color I need:

.h

```
@interface DataViewCustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIColor* cellColor;
    UIColor* standardColor;
}
- (void) setCellColor: (UIColor*)color;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation DataViewCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setCellColor: (UIColor*)color
{
    cellColor = color;
}

- (void) spreadBackgroundColor: (UIView*)that withColor: (UIColor*)bkColor
{
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [that.subviews objectEnumerator];
    id anObject;

    while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        if([anObject isKindOfClass: [UIView class]])
        {
            ((UIView*)anObject).backgroundColor = bkColor;
            [self spreadBackgroundColor:anObject withColor:bkColor];
        }
    }
}

- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; // layouts the cell as UITableViewCellStyleValue2 would normally look like

    if(!self.selected && NULL != cellColor)
    {
        [self spreadBackgroundColor:self withColor:cellColor];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

When I call setCellColor with the color I want, all goes well, but when I haven't found a way to set the original color back: when I set `[UIColor clearColor]` with UITableViewStylePlain style the results is not good-looking.

[image: Wrong result]

How can I achieve a good result, without a missing cell separator line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by myself. I used the following code in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` instead of subclassing:

```
    UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //The color you want
    cell.backgroundView = bg;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
    [bg release];
```

Answer (score 10):

I was having a similar problem and found edo42's answer.  However I was then having an issue with the background behind the text in the cell not displaying the background color I set.  I believe this is due to the style: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

In case others stumble upon this question, I believe the better solution for this is found in this question:

BackgroundColor of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle labels?
[BackgroundColor of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005050/backgroundcolor-of-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-labels)

Answer reprinted here:

To change the background color of the table view cell, you'll need to set it in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: rather than tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: otherwise it won't have any effect, for example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't before you set the new cell color, capture the old cell color in a UIColor variable. 
try 
UIColor *originalColor = anObject.backgroundColor;
then later when you want to change back to that just change the cell color to originalColor.

Comment: what does it do? change the color at all?

Comment: I had some memory problems but i fixed it, it returns gray color

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to adjust the color from within the custom cell's .m file, rather than the tableViewController. Seems more intuitive, and it's slightly easier. Just adjust the color as necessary in the methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

and

```
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Note: make sure you call the super of these methods too at the end of the call, e.g. if you want to make your cell green on touch:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
     self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
     [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Also, in my experience, it's not worth adjusting the color in touchesEnded, because your cell often won't adjust in-time for quick selections by the user.

Answer (score 0):

you should always provide changes for cell in willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndex instead of cellForRowAtIndex method , as per Apple Documentation

This Works !!

Answer (score 0):

Change the color in the following delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (...){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```