# How to set a color for a Cell on a TableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tableview, cell

I want the whole cell printed in blue but it only shows a little band.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];    
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
return cell;}
```

My screen capture is this:

[image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346721/uitableviewcell-background-color-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line after **[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];** line:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer :** [`tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way `UITableView` changes a cell's background color during selection, you must implement [`tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a) and set the cell background there. You should set the background of the whole cell rather than just its contentView, otherwise the accessory views will not be highlighted.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    cell.backgroundColor = ...;
}
```

You may also need to make the various subviews in the cell have transparent background colors.

```
cell.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.titleLabel.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];    
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
return cell;}
```